# PySpark map not working

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark

I am new to Apache Spark and a simple map function implemented as

```py
from pyspark import  SparkContext
sc = SparkContext( 'local', 'pyspark')

f = open("Tweets_tokenised.txt")
tokenised_tweets = f.readlines()

f = open("positive.txt")
pos_words=f.readlines()
f = open("negative.txt")
neg_words=f.readlines()
def sentiment(line):
    global pos_words
    global neg_words
    pos = 0
    neg = 0

    for word in line.split():
        if word in pos_words:
            pos=pos+1

        if word in neg_words:
            neg=neg+1

    if(pos > neg):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
dist_tweets=sc.textFile("Tweets_tokenised.txt").map(sentiment)
#(lambda line: sentiment(line))
dist_tweets.saveAsTextFile("RDD.txt")
```

Basically I am reading a file(containing tokenised and stemmed tweets) and then doing a simple positive-negative word count on it within the map function.(3rd line from the end)But RDD.txt has nothing in it.The function sentiment is not being called at all.
Can someone point out the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the value of a global variable inside a `map` transformation in `Apache Spark` to achieve this you need an [Accumulator](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=accumulator#pyspark.Accumulator), however even using using them I think that is not the correct approach.

In your case if your `pos_words` and `neg_words` are not so big, you could define them as [Broadcast](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=accumulator#pyspark.Broadcast) lists, and then count by `sentiment`.

Something like:

```py
pos = sc.broadcast(["good", "gold", "silver"])
neg = sc.broadcast(["evil", "currency", "fiat"])

# I will suppose that every record is a different tweet and are stored in tuples.
tweets = sc.parallelize([("banking", "is", "evil"), ("gold", "is", "good")])

(tweets
 .flatMap(lambda x: x)
 .map(lambda x: (1 if x in pos.value else -1 if x in neg.value else 0, 1))
 .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b).take(3))

# notice that I count neutral words.
# output -> [(0, 3), (1, 2), (-1, 1)]
```

Note, you can check the example right [here](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/2485090270202665/3256543495308294/8589256059752547/latest.html).

PD: If your idea was to count the positive and negative words per message, the approach vary very slightly.